# Laravel post rute not working for root paths

Tags: laravel, post, routes

I'm trying to setup my routes like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ValidatorController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', [ValidatorController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::post('/', [ValidatorController::class, 'process']);
```

but doesn't work, the browser inspector gets this, and redirects again to the index controller:

```
URL de la solicitud: http://localhost/ssl_validador/public
Método de la solicitud: POST
Código de estado: 301 Moved Permanently
Dirección remota: [::1]:80
Directiva de sitio de referencia: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Instead if i do this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ValidatorController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::redirect('/', 'proc');
Route::get('proc', [ValidatorController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::post('proc', [ValidatorController::class, 'process']);
```

Any idea why?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

please check if there is any '/' route exist in our routes file.

You can view your route list by run this comman in your terminal `php artisan route:list`

Comment: There aren't, that is the weird thing...

Comment: please share your web.php file code

Comment: That is my web php file.. i onñy have 2 routes defined :(